# collapseByDefault not working in Nav-component from Office UI Fabric

Tags: 2016, spfx, office-ui-fabric-react, office-ui-fabric

I try to build a navigation with spfx. Its working fine but I want to have the navigation collapsed. It seems that the property is not assigned or recognized by SPFx (it is running but with no effect).

My navigation element:

```
<Nav
  groups={ this.state.groupedPages }
/>
```

And the groupedPages-object:

[image: Navigation object]

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: are you implementing the `INavLinkGroup` interface ? Just looked at it, it doesnt have `url` property. Any console errors ?

Comment: It has the url property (in the screenshot: at the bottom). And yes I implementing the INavLinkGroup. Unfortunately no console errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some try and error I found the *"solution"*

collapseByDefault is at this point completely lossless. You have to add to the group the following property to get it work.

```
isExpanded: true
```

*Note: This seems not to apply to the root level of the Nav-component...*